# Microsoft Access formato condicional si un valor es "x" y mayor a 6 meses

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access-2010

Tengo una base de datos en **Access**, hay registros que están en valor "Pending" y tienen una fecha mayor a 6 meses por lo que quiero hacer que el campo de fecha se ponga en color rojo si la condición es la siguiente:

**Si el campo "Status = Pending" y la fecha es > Seis Meses entonces pintar el fondo del campo fecha en color rojo.**

Hasta ahora esta formula es algo parecido pero no funciona ya que colorea cualquier fecha por igual

`DateAdd("m",-6, Date())`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano a la comunidad por su ayuda.

Comment: Quizás tengas la fecha en un campo de texto y tengas que convertirlo a fecha

Answer (score 0):

La expresión tiene un error de sintaxis. En Microsoft Access los nombres de los campos se escriben entre corchetes, por lo que en lugar de

```
AgregFecha("m",-6,Fecha())
```

se debería haber escrito

```
AgregFecha("m",-6,[Fecha])
```

[image]